# SELECT with conditions for preferential source

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, unique

I have a query which I've been using for sometime however I have a new scenario which I'm not sure how to handle.  The query below extracts avg pricing from a table called availables.  The problem I have now is that, the data which is contained in this table can come from one of two sources.  So I added a source field to the table.

The problem is one or both of these sources for any record may be blank which is fine now, or they may contain data for the same record (which is my problem).  The records are normally unique except for the new alternative sources.

IE

```
Room Date        Price   Source
27   2010-02-28  $27.99  1
27   2010-02-28  $25.99  2
```

I this one instance I need the query to pull only the first source and ignore the second, but only if they both exist.

```
SELECT 
    rooms.id, 
    name, 
    ppl, 
    private AS exclusive, 
    MIN(spots) AS spots, 
    AVG(availables.price) AS price FROM "rooms" 
INNER JOIN 
    "availables" ON availables.room_id = rooms.id 
WHERE 
    (("rooms".hostel_id = 6933) AND 
     (rooms.active IS true AND bookdate BETWEEN '2011-02-20' AND '2011-02-22')) 
GROUP BY 
    rooms.id, name, ppl, private ORDER BY price
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

add a subquery like:

```
inner join
  (select Room, Date, min(Source) as Source
  from availables
  group by Room, Date) first_available
on first_available.Room = available.Room
    and first_available.Date = available.Date
    and first_available.Source = available.Source
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    rooms
JOIN    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ON (room_id, date) *
        FROM    availables
        ORDER BY
                room_id, date, source
        ) a
ON      a.room_id = rooms.id
WHERE   …
```

Comment: Excellent illustration of `SELECT DISTINCT ON`; however, holden should be aware that if he happens to have more than one row with the same `room_id`, `date` and `source` (e.g. assuming that when a couple makes reservations he inserts two rows with the two names and the same `room_id`, `date` and `source`) then `SELECT DISTINCT ON` will only keep one of them. If he has a single row per `room+date+source` then the `SELECT DISTINCT ON` could be faster than the aggregate join in the other post.